# Using Pandas to copy data from one workbook worksheet to another

Tags: python

In the below, I am trying to read data from one file (in path1) from tab "PoolResults" and I am trying to write this data to another file (in path2) with an existing tab "PoolResults". The second file has several tabs and "PoolResults" is just one of them. However, the below code upon execution just deletes all tabs and creates a new one called PoolResults with the data in it.

How can I amend the code so it literally just copies the data from the first file's relevant tab and pastes it into the second file's PoolResults tab. I don't want any other changes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

path1 = r'\\ant\dept\LMA\EU Capacity Planning\EU SLOPE Output\WK52\Archive\UK SLOPE WK52 - Fri PM - Releases WK53 .xlsx'

path2 = r'C:\Users\samiuop\Documents\UK WK48 PF Master EOW.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(path1, sheet_name="PoolResults")df2 = 

df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

df2.to_excel(path2,sheet_name='PoolResults',index= False)
```